# Why does the rendered and baked lighting differ so much?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texture-baking

This is the rendered preview:

[image: rendered preview]

And this is the combined bake:

[image: combined bake]

What am I doing wrong here? I want my baked texture to look like the rendered preview.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was switch to CPU (I have GPU problems on my Mac) and decrease render samples to speed up the bake and I got this:

[image]

My thought is that perhaps your problem was with the GPU since that is the only relevant thing that I changed (depending on what GPU you have, some features of Blender don't work, for example, HDR lighting).

Here is the baked image with higher samples:

[image]

Comment: I'm running a fairly new AMD GPU, maybe that's the issue, either way switching to CPU fixed several issues I've been having with baked lighting for some time now, thank you so much!
I tried to find a list of "compatible" GPUs, do you know if any such list exists?

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html AMD has awful support to say the least.